# get_or_create throws Integrity Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Given that the whole point of object.get_or_create() is to get the object if it already exists, I fail to see why it's throwing an integrity error for this code:

```
class UserAdd(TemplateView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    form = UserAddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        myemail = form.cleaned_data['email']
        mypass = form.cleaned_data['password']
        if myemail and mypass:
            myuser,created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=myemail, username=myemail, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
            if created:
                myuser.set_password(mypass)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Here is the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'user@domain.com' for key 'username_UNIQUE'")
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: A User exists with this username, but not with these first_name, last_name or email.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The parameters sent into the `get_or_create` method need to match exactly, or django's ORM would try to create a new object, and since a primary key/unique column constraint would be violated, you are getting the error.

Try this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    myemail = form.cleaned_data['email']
    mypass = form.cleaned_data['password']
    if myemail and mypass:
        myuser,created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=myemail, defaults = {'username': myemail, 'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name})
        if created:
            myuser.set_password(mypass)

return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Read more on [`get_or_create` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). The `defaults=` argument is what you needed.

Comment: Can you not put the password in the defaults?

Comment: no, because `set_password` would hash the password and store it in the database. That is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Right. I also needed myuser.save() after the set_password

Answer (score 0):

You are asking django to fetch a record based on four conditions:

- email
- username
- first_name
- last_name

So all four fields combined does not have a record.

You should do:

```
myuser, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
   username=myemail, defaults={'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': last_name, 'email': myemail})
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. if there was no record, get_or_create would've created it. That's what get_or_create is for and user is already using it. The IntegrityError is shown because of unique constraint failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar error after redefining model's `save()` method. It turns out that in case you call `save` more than once inside your model, all consequent calls should be made with `force_insert=True` keyword argument. In my case I had to change `self.save(*args, **kwargs)` to `self.save()` on second call to get rid of the error.
For more details read here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28253