# django get_or_create throws Integrity Error

Tags: django, database

I have read this thread:
[get_or_create throws Integrity Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362085/get-or-create-throws-integrity-error)

But still not fully understand when get_or_create returns **False** or **IntegrityError**.

I have the following code:

```
django_username = 'me'
user = get_user_model().objects.filter(username=django_username).first()

action_history, action_added = ActionModel.objects.get_or_create(
                date=date_obj,  # date object 
                account_name=unique_name,  # e.g. account1234
                target=follower_obj, # another model in django
                user=user,  # connected django user
                defaults={'identifier': history['user_id']}
            )
```

While the model looks like:

```
class ActionModel(models.Model):
    """
    A model to store action history.

    """

    identifier = models.BigIntegerField(
        _("identifier"), null=True, blank=True) # target id
    account_name = models.CharField(_("AccountName"), max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)  # account name of the client
    date = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)  # action date
    target = models.ForeignKey(Follower, verbose_name=_("Target"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # username of the done-on action
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        editable=False,
        db_index=True,
    )  # django user that performed the action

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Action")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Actions")
        unique_together = [
            ['account_name','date','target'],
        ]
```

Sometimes it return IntegrityError, and sometimes (when unique constrain exists it will return False  on created).

Comment: The docs say:

> If an object needs to be created and the key already exists in the database, an IntegrityError will be raised.

Comment: @MarkR. How come it is not catched in the get before the create ? I send all the unique values to it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unique_together constraint.
Lets imagine you have object in db with following data
account_name='bob', date='2020-12-12', target='b', user='12'

In you get_or_create method you are doing this

```
ActionModel.objects.get_or_create(
            date='2020-12-12', 
            account_name='bob',  
            target='b', 
            user="13"
        )
```

you providing exactly this three parameters with this data, but user this time is 13, so django could not find any object and it tries to create one, but with this parametres you cant create object because there is unique constraint

Comment: Can I add user to the unique constrain ? will it effect the exist DB ? unique_together = [
            ['account_name','date','target', 'user']

Comment: yes you can also add user to constraints if it fits your application logic, but be careful, there might be problems if you have 2 or more objects with unique problem

Comment: if it happens you can clear db with filtering and deleting the objects which violates constraints and try to migrate again

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I figured it out, I sent:

```
account_name = 'adi'
date = '07-02-21'
target = 'nana1'
user = 'me'
```

While it was not exist with the specific user = 'me' but with user = None:

```
account_name = 'adi'
date = '07-02-21'
target = 'nana1'
user = None
```

So the get was failing and the created try to duplicate the unique_together =      ['account_name','date','target'].